# Do Behirs hoard treasure?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, treasure

I've never run a Behir and am considering sticking one in a campaign setting I'm working on. I have a pretty straight-forward question: Do Behirs have treasure hoards?

The entry in the MM doesn't do much to answer this. They seem to be motivated by nothing but sustenance, and in "swallowing their prey whole" it doesn't suggest anything of value would be left behind.

My exposure to this monster is limited to page 25 of the MM, so there is a lot I could be missing here.

Comment: Please answer in answers, not comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing in the entry explicitly calls out that it hoards treasure (as with many monsters), however it does have intelligence and therefore certainly could know the value of it, if for nothing else but to bait potential prey into its waiting jaws or bribing its way out of being potential lightning-seasoned steaks.

Whereas individual DMs may disagree on what monsters hoard and/or carry treasure, the DMG on page 133 simply states:

> The placement of treasure is left to your discretion. The key is to
>   make sure the players feel rewarded for playing, and that their
>   characters are rewarded for overcoming dangerous challenges.

Of course one monster might spend time hoarding where another of the same type may not, as it may not see the benefit of doing so or be of a different type. There was a Dragon Magazine article years ago describing a dragon that hoarded nothing but "knowledge" and forewent monetary types entirely, except presumably to buy more knowledge.

Previous editions did have them have a hoard however. 5e has gotten away from such explicit distinctions though, so it is left to you to decide.