# Random Dungeon Generation: How Individual Treasure or Horde Treasure

Tags: dnd-5e, treasure, dungeon

So I've got a dungeon I've mapped out using the DMG's random Dungeon Tables. I've fleshed it out save for the treasure. There are times I have "Monster" or "Monster with treasure."

There's a separate room designated for treasure, so obviously, use the "Treasure Horde" table for random treasure. But for the individual (or small groups) labeled "with/guarding treasure" should I just use the "Individual Treasure" table?

My problem is the wording of the Individual Treasure Table, which makes it seem like EVERY creature or monster is "worth" this much in reward. But I'm concerned about unbalancing the game if I do hordes of treasure every time it calls for treasure in the dungeon.

Comment: [Pseudo-related](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/92603/do-behirs-hoard-treasure/92605#92605)

Comment: So you're having trouble with how much loot to hand out during a game? Are related guide lines within the book not helping?